# Call a hapi route from another route

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I am pretty new to HapiJS. I am building a service where I have two routes /route1 and /route2 both are using the plugin architecture. I have registered both as plugins on my manifest file.

I want to call /route1 from /route2 so /route2 depends on the payload reply from /route1. I've been looking at putting the logic of /route2 on /route1 on the pre-handler but I want to keep them separately.

Don't know how to call a registered plugin from another the thing is that both plugins (routes) are making networks requests. Thanks for reading.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you specify that you don't want to use a shared handler/route prerequisite (which would be my first choice), you could make an actual request using a http client ([Wreck](https://github.com/hapijs/wreck), [request](https://github.com/request/request), [http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) or the like).

Another, more efficient way that doesn't involve actually making a network request is to use hapi's built-in [`server.inject()`](https://github.com/hapijs/shot) method provided by [Shot](https://github.com/hapijs/shot). This will inject a request into your server and get the response, which you can use. Here's an example:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');

var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 4000 });

var plugin1 = function (server, options, next) {

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/route1',
        handler: function (request, reply) {

            reply('Hello');
        }
    });

    next();
};

plugin1.attributes = { name: 'plugin1' };

var plugin2 = function (server, options, next) {

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/route2',
        handler: function (request, reply) {

            server.inject('/route1', function (res) {

                reply(res.payload + ' World!');
            });
        }
    });

    next();
};

plugin2.attributes = { name: 'plugin2' };

server.register([plugin1, plugin2], function (err) {

    if (err) throw err;
    server.start(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Started');
    });
});
```

Note that the fact the routes are in plugins here is irrelevant. I've merely included it so it's close to your situation.

Shot and `server.inject()` are primarily used for testing but there are legitimate runtime uses like this too.

If you make a request to `/route2`, this will invoke `/route1` handler and get the payload:

```
$ curl localhost:4000/route2
Hello World!
```

Comment: Note that it does not forward headers, status-code and potential errors if that's what you want take a look at https://github.com/hapijs/discuss/issues/297#issuecomment-255593684