# Hapi js accessing one route from another

Tags: javascript, hapi.js

I have 2 routes test_01 and test_02.
When request comes to test_02 route, How do i access route test_01 and get its response data?

I'm not talking about forwarding route from test_02 to test_01

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/data/test_01',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        reply('test_01')
    }
})

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/data/test_02',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        // Get data from route '/data/test_01'
        var test_01_data = ''
        reply(test_01_data)
    }
})
```

Controller

```
Index = function () {}

Index.prototype = {

    test_01 : function (req, reply, data) {
        reply('test_01')
    },

    test_02 : function (req, reply, data) {
        reply('test_02')
    }
}

module.exports = Index
```

Comment: write the handler as a separate function and call it wherever required, so you could call it in test2 handler as well as test1 handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a separate controller function to be called from the handlers

```
var controllerfn = function(req,reply){
     //do stuff
  return 'test_01';
};
```

Call it as required

```
server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/data/test_01',
  handler: function (request, reply) {
             reply(controllerfn(request,reply);
  }
})  

server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/data/test_02',
  handler: function (request, reply) {
    // Get data from route '/data/test_01'
    var test_01_data = controllerfn(request,reply);
    reply(test_01_data)
  }
})
```

Comment: Hai, Im passing requests from route to controller. Within controller requests are processed and replied. If i try to return from controller i get undefined. I have updated my question with controller example

Comment: Did it work for you? in your routes are you calling the controller function?
Check this for similar discussion with a different approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069573/call-a-hapi-route-from-another-route?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse that route and not make another socket connection you can [inject](http://hapijs.com/api#serverinjectoptions-callback) to the other route.

```
  server.route({
      method: 'GET',
      path: '/data/test_01',
      handler: function (request, reply) {
          reply('test_01')
      }
  })

  server.route({
      method: 'GET',
      path: '/data/test_02',
      handler: function (request, reply) {
          // Get data from route '/data/test_01'
          request.server.inject({
            url: {
              pathname: '/data/test_01'
            }
          }, (res) => {
            var test_01_data = res.result;
            return reply(test_01_data);
          })
      }
  })
```